# Python Numpy - Reading elements of a Vector Numpy Array as numerical values rather than as Numpy Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector, dereference

Suppose I have a Numpy Array that has dimensions of nx1 (n rows, 1 column). My usage of this is for implementing 3D vectors as 3x1 Matrices using Numpy, but the application can be extended for nx1 Vector Matrices:

```
In [0]: import numpy as np

In [1]: foo = np.array([ ['a11'], ['a21'], ['a31'], ..., ['an1'] ])
```

I want to be able to access the values of the array by dereferencing one value.

```
In [2]: foo[0]
Out[2]: 'a11'

In [3]: foo[n]
Out[3]: 'an1'
```

However, by the general formatting of Numpy Arrays, a Vector array would be considered a 2D Array and would require 2 values to dereference it: I would have to use `foo[0][0]` or `foo[0][n]` to get the same values. I could use `np.transpose` to Transpose the Vector into one row, but the syntax continues to produce a 2D Numpy Array that requires 2 values to dereference: hence

```
In [4]: np.transpose(foo)[0] == foo[0][0]
Out[4]: array([ True, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [5]: np.transpose(foo)[0][0] == foo[0][0]
Out[5]: True
```

This would nullify any advantage that transposing would provide. How can I access the elements of a Vector Numpy Array using only one Dereferencing Value?

Comment: You can write `foo = np.array(['a11', 'a21', 'a31', ..., 'an1'] )`.  Then `foo[0]` `'a11'`.  Numpy has true *n*-dimensional arrays, and *n* can be 1.

Comment: Also, in the 2-d case, you can write `foo[0,0]`.

Comment: I like the 2nd suggestion you made, but the first one takes away from the original formatting of Vector Matrices as I will be using them in Matrix Multiplication. I suppose I can always Transpose 1D Arrays whenever I perform said Mux operations, but it doesn't seem appealing to have to do transpositions like that.

Comment: *" I suppose I can always Transpose 1D Arrays ..."*  Actually, you can't. :)  A transpose interchanges two dimensions.  A 1-d array has only one dimensional, so a transpose doesn't do anything.

Comment: Huh, true fact that. Just tried it out. Seems legit. Thanks for the tip. I wouldn't have figured that out until things hit the fan.

Comment: And you wouldn't be the first. :)

Comment: *"the first one takes away from the original formatting of Vector Matrices as I will be using them in Matrix Multiplication"*  There is nothing wrong with storing your vectors as 2-d arrays with shape (n, 1), but I'll point out that  matrix mulitplication of a 2-d array and a 1-d array works as you would probably like it to.  E.g. if `a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])` and `x = np.array([-1, 3])`, then `a.dot(x)` gives `array([5, 9])`.  (Also, if you are using a recent version of numpy with Python 3.5, you can write that product as `a @ x`.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [numpy.ndarray.tolist()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) function:

```
In [1]: foo = np.array([ ['a11'], ['a21'], ['a31'] ])
In [2]: foo.tolist()
Out[2]: [['an1'], ['a2n'], ['a3n']]

In [3]: foo.tolist()[0]
Out[3]: ['an1']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `foo` is a 2d array of strings:

```
In [354]: foo = np.array([ ['a11'], ['a21'], ['a31'], ['an1'] ])
In [355]: foo.shape
Out[355]: (4, 1)
In [356]: foo[0]   # selects a 'row'
Out[356]: 
array(['a11'], 
      dtype='<U3')
In [357]: foo[0,:]    # or more explicitly with the column :
Out[357]: 
array(['a11'], 
      dtype='<U3')
In [358]: foo[:,0]     # selects a column, results in a 1d array
Out[358]: 
array(['a11', 'a21', 'a31', 'an1'], 
      dtype='<U3')
In [359]: foo[0,0]     # select an element
Out[359]: 'a11'
```

Transpose is still 2d, just switching rows and columns:

```
In [360]: foo.T
Out[360]: 
array([['a11', 'a21', 'a31', 'an1']], 
      dtype='<U3')
In [361]: _.shape
Out[361]: (1, 4)
```

Ravel (or flatten) turns it into a 1d array, which can be accessed with just one index.

```
In [362]: foo.ravel()[1]
Out[362]: 'a21'
```

Your talk about matrix multiplication and such suggests that your array really isn't of strings, but that 'a21' represents an array, or is number.  So is it really a 2d numeric array, or maybe a 3d array?